# Finding the Java docs deprecated messages

Tags: java, javadoc, deprecated

How do I navigate to the informative messages about a deprecated class in Java documentation?

I have seen something like this in other answers:

From [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html) documentation:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

But how do I get to this informative message in the Java docs? All I can see is a DEPRECATED link at the top. I need the extra information so I can understand the reason for it being deprecated and use its alternative.

Comment: You mean inside your IDE? If so, which IDE do you use? If you have setup your Javadoc settings in your IDE correctly it should show up. At least it does in my Eclipse. Other than that, the official documentation contains everything, but you already linked that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? How to know when a class is deprecated in general? Or how to get quick access via your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be any reliable way to do that.  The text you have found is an informal advice about the class.  This class is NOT formally deprecated.  Deprecated means something very specific in the Java context.  It is much stronger than *"use is discouraged in new code"*.

If a class or class member is *really* deprecated in Java, you will see a `@Deprecated` annotation in the source code.  This is what the Java tool chain pays attention to.  There may also be a `@deprecated` javadoc tag with an explanation and suggestions for alternatives, where appropriate.  That is what is turned into the "Deprecated:" heading in the javadocs.

Finding informal advice like the example you have identified would probably require searching the Java library codebase or the javadoc tree for key phrases like "legacy" and "not recommended".  You would then need to manually filter  out the false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the reason a class was deprecated is because a better alternative was found or because it's simply no longer required.

As for the `deprecated link at the top` you mentioned, I assume you mean the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Well, like you said, those *are* all the information you'll find, and they're pretty descriptive too.

Let's take the constructor `Date(int year, int month, int day)` for example, if you scroll down to the [deprecated constructor section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#constructor), you can find the following:

> **java.sql.Date(int, int, int)**
>
> instead use the constructor Date(long date)

and it does the same thing for every classes/methods/interfaces marked with the `@Deprecated` annotation in the JDK.

Also, for [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html), if you read just below the line you quoted, it says the following:

> The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be
>   used to break up a string into its basic tokens:
>
> ```
> String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
> for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
>     System.out.println(result[x]);
> ```

Basically, `StringTokenizer` is no longer necessary because the `String` object now has a `split` method, which makes `StringTokenizer` useless.